# Hidden Notebook inherits NotebookDynamicExpression?

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, clipboard, inheritance

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

The following behavior is stably reproduced with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1, 11.0.1 and 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Set the `NotebookDynamicExpression`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[nb = EvaluationNotebook[], UpdateInterval -> .1]]
```

Evaluate `Dynamic[nb]`:

```
Dynamic[nb]
```

[image: screenshot]

Everything is as expected so far. Now just select the code `Dynamic[nb]` and copy it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Here is what becomes:

[image: screenshot]

By evaluating `nb` you occasionally can get the hidden `NotebookObject`:

```
nb
```

[image: screenshot]

This object isn't listed in `Notebooks[]`:

```
Notebooks[]
```

[image: screenshot]

What happens here? From where comes the hidden `NotebookObject`? Why `nb` periodically switches between the two `NotebookObject`s? Is it a bug?

Comment: It seems to be a clipboard notebook, not sure why it inherits `NotebookDynamicExpression`.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, `NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[]` returns a Notebook with the `NotebookDynamicExpression`. Then it is certainly a bug, right?

Comment: I'd agree, definitely worth reporting

Comment: Similar pb with OSX and MMA 11.1.1 : i don't get the "blinking/switching"  dynamic object, but the `nb` command returns `NotebookObject[16]`. I have recently played with `NotebookDynamicExpression` and `Refresh` and observed some strange similar switching effects in Dynamic but not very reproducible, i gave up.

Comment: @SquareOne Does `NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[]` return a Notebook expression containing the `NotebookDynamicExpression`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I actually get now the switching effect IF I copy (command+c) anything to the clipboard : this action triggers the start of the switching. With a fresh session/kernel (and empty clipboard) i confirm no effect. And `NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[]` returns an expression with the `NotebookDynamicExpression` only in the case where i trigger the switching.

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I expect the core `NotebookObject` is copied so that multi-selection is potentially easier. Clumsy approach, if so.